# How do I keep the cell, but change the date for a summary column it's linked to?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, tabs, column

I have a workbook with a month's data. Each day is tabbed on the bottom. The data for each day is entered in a row.  At the end of the month I have spreadsheets that do a monthly summary of specific data.  Each summary column has a cell that is linked to a specific day's data.
The way I'm doing it now is highlighting a cell in a column, going back to the day's cell I need, type in ='1'!A1 (for example), highlight the formula, copy it, then paste it to every cell in the column.  Then, I Change the "date" like so: ='1'!A1
='2'!A1
='3'!A1   etc.

There has to be a much easier way to do this.  I can't figure it out.  I'm self taught in excel, so I'm not sure I'm explaining or wording it correctly.  I don't know what to ask in a Google search.  I'm stumped and getting very tired of doing 15+ summary columns every month.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Say you put this is cell A2 of the summary sheet and plan to copy downwards

```
=INDIRECT((ROW()-1)&"!A1")
```

If say you need 1!A2 in column B then

```
=INDIRECT((ROW()-1)&"!A"&COLUMN())
```

TAKE NOTE:
Indirect makes a reference from text. Problem is indirect is volatile, meaning Excel will recalculate it at each and every opportunity (vs selective recalculation only when "inputs" to normal functions changes). Volatile functions can make your spreadsheet noticeably slower, especially large spreadsheets.